# Strikeout numbers from an enumerated list

Tags: lists, enumerate, strikeout

I would like to have a simple enumerated list like

```
\begin{enumerate}
   \item First item
   \item Second item
\end{enumerate}
```

where I strike through "(1)" and "(2)" but not the text "First item" and "Second item". Would that be possible?

Update: could I have only (1) stroke-through but not (2)?

Comment: This one https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254944/strikeout-all-text-including-enumerated-lists is related, but I could not use it.

Comment: What do you mean by "...and then"? It's not clear to me. When you typeset the list, do you want it to have stroke-through numbers or not?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I now clarified. Yes I want it to have stroke-through numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `ulem` and the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\sout{(\arabic*)}]
        \item  First item
        \item Second item
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, that was exactly what I was trying to do!

Comment: Could I perhaps erase certain numbers but not all?

Comment: This should be a different question, but the answer is yes, if you do it manually:  `\begin{enumerate} \item[\sout{(1)}]  First item \item[(2)] Second item \end{enumerate}`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 2):

If I've well understood what you want, it can easily be done with the `cancel` and `enumitem` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cancel} 

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\cancel{\arabic*}. ]
   \item First item
   \item Second item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is a very good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `\setcounter{enumi}` to get numbers at your list. When you use enumerate environment.
For example:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{3}
\item Something.
\item Something else.
\item Another element.
\item The last item in the list.
\end{enumerate}
```

At this exampling the counter in text starts with 3rd number, because it is set there `\setcounter{enumi}{3}`
Also LaTex has different types of enumerating text:
Default counters in LaTeX

For document structure

part chapter section subsection  subsubsection  paragraph  subparagraph    page

For floats
equation
figure
table

For footnotes
footnote
mpfootnote

**For the enumerate environment**
enumi
enumii
enumiii
enumiv

Comment: I am sorry, could you provide an example?

Comment: Do you mean that there is some type of enumerating that has stroke-through numbers instead of regular ones? Because I want the numbers to count from the first item as usual, only with a line through them.

Comment: The solution that you showed https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254944/strikeout-all-text-including-enumerated-lists uses not the simple LaTex, It uses additional libraries as \usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}