# Is there a way have breakable framed boxes?

Tags: line-breaking, boxes, fbox

Here is a command I have:

```
\newcommand{\numbox}[2]{$^{\circled{#1}}${\fbox{#2}}}
```

What it does is boxing and numbering a text. However I for the box to break nicely across lines. In command `\fbox{text}` the text may stick out of the margins if the line is full. However I want to write a conditional for this case. Such as:

```
until text finished
after every word: 
   if there is \linebreak:
       end \fbox
       continue text with \fbox
```

[image]
[image]

In above I added Images!

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

I used multiline colored box but as I said, since sentences are small it doesn’t look that nice tbh. Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  I'm having trouble following your question.  I understand your `\numbox` definition, but everything after that is harder to understand.  What conditional are you wanting?  Could you create a MWE that shows where your conditional should do something different?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want breakable `\fbox`es?

Comment: you could look at soul or ulem for breakable highlighting but don't you really just want `\fbox{\parbox{.9\textwidth}{ text allowing line breaking in a box}}` ?

Comment: @plante actually yes. But I want to use it in \newcommand :)

Comment: @davidcarlisle I am going to check it thanks :)

Comment: I edited my comment t explain it visually :))

Comment: @davidcarlisle \fbox{\parbox{.9\textwidth}{ text allowing line breaking in a box}} this does ends line inside the box

Comment: Looks like OP want to frame each line separately. Otherwise it's just https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25903/how-to-put-a-long-piece-of-text-in-a-box

Comment: To clarify, do you (OP) want to align the right side of the boxes?

Comment: How about this as an option: [Multi-line box around a sentence in a paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116900/5764)

Comment: @AtahanHaznedar but why don't you want to box the paragraph, as you do for the question, boxing each line as you show for the solution will never look nice or be very readable with the double lrule between each line of text

Comment: @user202729 sure that's what the OP says is wanted. But trying to persuade them otherwise:-)

Comment: user202729 tbh I wanted to align right side of the boxes, however, I really liked the werner's option. In case I can't find a solution I will use that. Thanks for the answers :)

Comment: @DAVİDcharlise Because some sentences are very small. If I end up boxing it at the end of line and finish it at the beginning of the line it would look like a mess. I tried werner's option and it looks great actually. However as I said some sentences are very small and they look strange in those sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but just a suggestion: `tcolorbox`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\newtcbox[auto counter]{\solution}[1][]{%
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
tcbox raise=-4mm,
grow to left by=-90pt, 
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=-90pt,yshift=-20pt}, 
enhanced,
tcbox width=auto limited, 
title= Solution ~\thetcbcounter #1}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\solution{\lipsum[1][1]}
\solution{\lipsum[3][1]}
\solution{\lipsum[3][1-5]}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also not an answer, but to my mind one of the most useful source:
https://tools.ietf.org/doc/texlive-doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf