# Draw a line from a multi-line boxed text to a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I've drawn a multi-line box around a text  in a paragraph using the code at [multi-line-box-around-a-sentence-in-a-paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116900/multi-line-box-around-a-sentence-in-a-paragraph)
For simplicity, let's call this multi-line boxed text as *highlighted text*.

Now I'd like to draw a line from this *highlighted text* to a TikZ node I've formed. Here is the MWE:

```
% The code must be run at least 2 times!
% The code from here until the begin{document} is taken from:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116900/multi-line-box-around-a-sentence-in-a-paragraph
% with minor additions / modifications
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
  remember picture with id/.style={%
    remember picture,
    overlay,
    save picture id=#1,
  },
  save picture id/.code={%
    \edef\pgf@temp{#1}%
    \immediate\write\pgfutil@auxout{%
      \noexpand\savepointas{\pgf@temp}{\pgfpictureid}}%
  },
  if picture id/.code args={#1#2#3}{%
    \@ifundefined{save@pt@#1}{%
      \pgfkeysalso{#3}%
    }{
      \pgfkeysalso{#2}%
    }
  }
}

\def\savepointas#1#2{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname save@pt@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\def\tmk@labeldef#1,#2\@nil{%
  \def\tmk@label{#1}%
  \def\tmk@def{#2}%
}

\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{pic}{%
  \pgfutil@in@,{#1}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \tmk@labeldef#1\@nil
  \else
    \tmk@labeldef#1,(0pt,0pt)\@nil
  \fi
  \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tmk@label}{%
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone\tmk@def
  }{%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\csname save@pt@\tmk@label\endcsname}\save@orig@pic%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\pgfpictureid}\save@this@pic%
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@this@pic}%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@orig@pic}%
  \advance\pgf@x by -\pgf@xa
  \advance\pgf@y by -\pgf@ya
  }%
}
\newcommand\tikzmark[2][]{%
\tikz[remember picture with id=#2] #1;}
\makeatother

\newcommand\BoxedText[4][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[#1]
  let \p1=(pic cs:#2), \p2=(pic cs:#3) in
  ([yshift=-0.8ex]\p1) --
  ([yshift=2ex]\p1) -- 
  ([xshift=3pt,yshift=2ex]\p1-|current page text area.east) -- 
  ([xshift=3pt,yshift=2ex]\p2-|current page text area.east) --
  ([yshift=2ex]\p2) --
  ([yshift=-0.8ex]\p2) --
  ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=-0.8ex]\p2-|current page text area.west) --
  ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=-0.8ex]\p1-|current page text area.west) --
  cycle node (#4) {}
; % (#4) is added in order to name the node 
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\BoxedText[]{start1}{end1}{MYPARAGRAPH}

% \blindtext[100] Nope, this doesn't work in this particular case.
Some text goes here. I have to add some text manually here. blindtext[100] doesn't work here. Sorry. Some text goes here. Some text goes here.Some text goes here.Some text goes here. Some text goes here. 
\tikzmark{start1} Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here.Some text goes here.Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text Some text goes here \tikzmark{end1} Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here.Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text Some text goes here

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \node[rectangle,
    below=0.5cm of MYPARAGRAPH,
    draw=blue,]
  (MYNOTE){\footnotesize Here is my note};
  \draw[very thick,blue] 
  (MYPARAGRAPH) -| (MYNOTE);
\end{tikzpicture}     

\end{document}
```

The `\draw`ed line seems to end at the region where the paragraph ends. I'd like to extend the `\draw` 'ed line up to the border of the highlighted text like this:

[image: node to node line]

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do that is to place a coordinate when drawing your box around the text. Here I did `coordinate[midway](leftside)` to place this coordinate in the middle of the left side of your box.

Then, instead of trying to draw from a node to this place, I found it easier to do the opposite: drawing from the left side of the box to somewhere below the text and placing your node at the end.

[image: draw from text to node]

Obviously, the distances can be adjusted as you wish.

```
% The code must be run at least 2 times!
% The code from here until the begin{document} is taken from:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116900/multi-line-box-around-a-sentence-in-a-paragraph
% with minor additions / modifications
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
  remember picture with id/.style={%
    remember picture,
    overlay,
    save picture id=#1,
  },
  save picture id/.code={%
    \edef\pgf@temp{#1}%
    \immediate\write\pgfutil@auxout{%
      \noexpand\savepointas{\pgf@temp}{\pgfpictureid}}%
  },
  if picture id/.code args={#1#2#3}{%
    \@ifundefined{save@pt@#1}{%
      \pgfkeysalso{#3}%
    }{
      \pgfkeysalso{#2}%
    }
  }
}

\def\savepointas#1#2{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname save@pt@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\def\tmk@labeldef#1,#2\@nil{%
  \def\tmk@label{#1}%
  \def\tmk@def{#2}%
}

\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{pic}{%
  \pgfutil@in@,{#1}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \tmk@labeldef#1\@nil
  \else
    \tmk@labeldef#1,(0pt,0pt)\@nil
  \fi
  \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tmk@label}{%
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone\tmk@def
  }{%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\csname save@pt@\tmk@label\endcsname}\save@orig@pic%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\pgfpictureid}\save@this@pic%
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@this@pic}%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@orig@pic}%
  \advance\pgf@x by -\pgf@xa
  \advance\pgf@y by -\pgf@ya
  }%
}
\newcommand\tikzmark[2][]{%
\tikz[remember picture with id=#2] #1;}
\makeatother

\newcommand\BoxedText[4][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[#1]
  let \p1=(pic cs:#2), \p2=(pic cs:#3) in
  ([yshift=-0.8ex]\p1) --
  ([yshift=2ex]\p1) -- 
  ([xshift=3pt,yshift=2ex]\p1-|current page text area.east) -- 
  ([xshift=3pt,yshift=2ex]\p2-|current page text area.east) --
  ([yshift=2ex]\p2) --
  ([yshift=-0.8ex]\p2) --
  ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=-0.8ex]\p2-|current page text area.west) --
  ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=-0.8ex]\p1-|current page text area.west) coordinate[midway](leftside) --
  cycle node (#4) {}
; % (#4) is added in order to name the node 
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\BoxedText[]{start1}{end1}{MYPARAGRAPH}

% \blindtext[100] Nope, this doesn't work in this particular case.
Some text goes here. I have to add some text manually here. \blindtext[1]

Some text goes here. Some text goes here.Some text goes here.Some text goes here. Some text goes here. \tikzmark{start1} Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here.Some text goes here.Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text Some text goes here \tikzmark{end1} Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here.Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text Some text goes here

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[very thick,blue]  (leftside) -|++ (-0.5,-2.2) -|++ (2,-.5) node [below,draw=blue,text=black] {\footnotesize Here is my note};
\end{tikzpicture}     

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That worked it out in a heartbeat. Plus, drawing from the *highlighted text* box to somewhere below the text and placing an unnamed node on the fly looks good too. However, there's one detail I couldn't understand: How did you know/ensure that the `\draw` would start from the `BoxedText` named `MYPARAGRAPH` without giving it the name `MYPARAGRAPH`? (My guess) Is it achieved by the `[remember picture, overlay]` options?

Comment: Like I said in my answer, I added a `coordinate` while drawing the `BoxedText`. Search `coordinate[midway](leftside)` into the code. This places a coordinate in the middle of the left vertical line of your `BoxedText` that you can access later in another `tikzpicture`, thanks to the `[remember picture, overlay]` option.